# Counters not counting correctly in rails app -- am I supposed to use increment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I have a Rails app that has the following models:

- `Project` (which has many tasks)
- `Task` (which belongs to a project, and has many task responses)
- `TaskResponse` (which belongs to a task)

For example, I might have a project where I ask people to take pictures of an animal. I want three different people to take pictures of each animal, so a task to take a picture of a butterfly might have three different task responses associated with it.

I want to keep track of the total number of completed responses, so I have the following code:

```
class TaskResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task

  before_save :update_responses_completed
  before_save :update_responses_in_progress

  # Statuses
  IN_PROGRESS = 1
  COMPLETED = 2
  SKIPPED = 3

  def update_responses_completed
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      if self.status == TaskResponse::COMPLETED && self.status_changed?
        # Update task & project counters
        self.task.num_responses_completed += 1
        self.project.num_responses_completed += 1

        self.task.save!
        self.project.save!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, these counters don't seem to be consistent. I *should* have:

- `self.project.num_responses_completed == self.project.tasks.map(&:num_responses_completed).inject(0, :+)`
- `self.task.num_responses_completed == self.task.task_responses.select { |tr| tr.status == TaskResponse::COMPLETED }.size`

But these don't seem to be true.

I can't figure out what's wrong. I'm not sure if there's some issue with caching, whether the `+=1` is being applied to an old cached value, or what. I see that there are `increment` and `increment_counter` methods in Rails, but I can't understand what the difference is between using those and `+= 1` (are they reloading the models or avoiding race conditions or something? I've searched StackOverflow, but I see inconsistent answers).

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I update a task response's status in the update function in my controller (which gets hit after a user submits a response). So it looks something like:

```
class TaskResponsesController
  def update
    tr = TaskResponse.find(params[:id])
    tr.update!(params)
    tr.status = TaskResponse::COMPLETED
    tr.save!
    redirect_to(tr)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you update the status ?

Comment: @Thomas Haratyk: Added the code. The status simply gets updated when the user fills out a form for the task response and submits.

Comment: Is there a reason for storing the number instead of using a simple count ? Because you'll have to handle every kind of status update and row deletion etc.... Are you concerned by performance ?

Comment: Yup, I'm storing a counter instead of counting every time for performance reasons. (I make these calls a lot.)